# How Can I ssh to an Existing ECS Fargate Managed Container for Debugging Errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an AWS ECS Fargate managed container that is running a service. At times I'm getting a `Socket accept failed, too many open files` error and to debug this, I would like to SSH to the container to see which process is causing this. How can I do this to an existing ECS fargate container with a task?

I read about ECS Exec but the documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html mentions that `You can't enable ECS Exec for existing tasks. It can only be enabled for new tasks.`.

Any advice/suggestions would be much appreciated as I'm not much familiar with the technologies involved here.

Comment: You can't SSH into Fargate containers. You can enable ECS Exec, which allows a connection similar to SSH, but it will require restarting the container.

Comment: Further to this, CloudWatch logging should be enabled at the cluster level as this can give you some visibility in what is happening at the container level.

Comment: @MarkB can I update my existing container to enable ECS Exec without having to create a new one? If its only restarting, I wouldn't have any problems

Comment: @Norman Sorry I'm new to AWS, how can I enable that?

Comment: Your existing container will be restarted after you change this setting.

Comment: @AnOldSoul you should be able to use the command line to update an existing cluster: `aws ecs update-cluster-settings --cluster cluster_name_or_arn --settings name=containerInsights,value=enabled|disabled --region us-east-1`.  Make sure your default profile points at this account, or use a profile that points to this account (in which case you would add `--profile=profile-name` to the end).  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-container-insights.html#cloudwatch-container-insights-working

Comment: @Norman I have cloud watch container insights enabled. One thing I see is that around the time of this error, `number of threads` and `FileDescriptorUse` go up very high. `FileDescriptorUse` gets to 99% actually. As the thread count seems to gradually increase over time, could we consider not properly closing threads a cause of this?

Comment: Yes, this seems to match the error that you described up front too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled 'initProcessEnabled' in container defination ?

If this parameter is not set to true then running fargate containers will not be accessible through shell.

Please refer below document.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_linuxparameters